# Is there a userspace TCP stack which operates as a TUN interface?

Tags: linux, tcp, tun

Is there a userspace TCP stack which operates as a TUN interface and with an API similar to POSIX on the application side?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, User-Mode Linux is such a stack. But it's probably a bit bigger than you wanted, since it contains a whole kernel.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux

You can also use LWIP: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/
See this thread: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lwip-users/2005-06/msg00024.html